# Next.js config breaks CSS of packages

Tags: css, webpack, sass, less, next.js

I configured next.js in order to use ant design and its components.
Here is the `next.config.js` file

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate');

module.exports = {
  ...withLess(
    withSass(nextTranslate({
      lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    }))
  ),
  images: {
    domains: ["storage.googleapis.com"],
  }
}
```

With this configuration, I am able to make ant design work and change the theme from one  `.less` file and I am getting the following warning :
`Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.`

So now, I am trying to use react-leaflet but it seems like this configuration is conflicting with the package's CSS. Map tiles are not displaying correctly and when I try import the CSS file (`node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css` ) directly in the component file. I am not able to access `url(images/layers-2x.png);`

How should I tweak the configuration in order to make both ant.d and react-leaflet packages work properly ? Or is it possible to use ant.d without a specific next.js configuration ?

PS: Next version 10.0.0